# Show the graph commutes, diagonal function.

Tags: category-theory

$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD}
                   X @>{f}>> Y\\
@V{\delta_X}VV @V{\delta_Y}VV \\
X\times X@>{f \times f}>> Y\times Y
\end{CD}$

Where, $\delta _{X,Y}$ is the diagonal of $X$ and $Y$ respectively.

I am trying to show the diagram commutes, and this is what I have so far:

$\delta _Y \circ f$, and $(f \times f)\circ \delta_X$ I am not sure I can see how the two functions are equal. Any Ideas?

Comment: Wait, is $X$ a set, or an element of the category?

Comment: @jMdA an element of catagory of sets.

Comment: And the morphisms are just functions? In that case this becomes a lot easier.

Comment: What is your defnition for $f \times f$? Also the left square is identical to the right square..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the UMP of $Y\times Y$, so if we have an arrow $X\to Y$, there is a unique arrow $X\to Y\times Y$, s.t. the induced triangles commute (so if $g: X\to Y$, and $h:X\to Y\times Y$, then this commutativity is where $g = h\pi_j$, where $\pi_j$ are the projections of $Y\times Y$ to the factors), but we have two such maps! Namely we have $f\times f\circ \delta_X$ and $<f,f>:X\to Y\times Y$ (the latter map is the one via the UMP of $Y\times Y$ from the arrow $X\to Y$), so they must be equal! We can see that $f\times f$ is compatible with the projections of $Y\times Y$ to the factors just by using the definition of $\delta_Y$ (induced by the map $1_Y:Y\to Y$) so you have the commutative triangle $\pi_j\delta_Y = 1_Y$, which makes $f\times f = \delta_Yf$. Your square commuting is a direct result of $<f,f> = f\times f\delta_y$ (I would draw all of these triangles out, namely the ones where $f\times f = \delta_y f$ which follows from connecting this with the triangle we know commutes right off the bat: where $\pi_j\delta_Y = 1_Y$ definitionally).

Comment: I am not sure what UMP is, but I added two extra definitions which might be relevant.

Comment: I think we have the same answer, but yours is more wordy, while mine is graphical.

Comment: @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost By the UMP I mean the defining property of the product $Y\times Y$, the one where: if you have an arrow $A\to Y$ you have a unique arrow $A\to Y\times Y$ compatible with the projections $\pi_j Y\times Y\to Y$.

Answer (score 2):

You can prove that both $\delta_Y \circ f$ and $(f \times f) \circ \delta_X$ are the product morphism associated with the pair of morphisms $f:X\rightarrow Y$ and $f:X\rightarrow Y$.

You can do this by drawing two diagrams.

$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD}
@.X\\
@.*@V{\delta_X}VV*\\
X @<{\pi_X}<<X\times X @>{\pi'_X}>> X\\
@V {f} VV@V{f\times f}VV @V{f}VV \\
Y @<{\pi_Y}<<Y\times Y@>{\pi'_Y}>> Y
\end{CD}$

(Please add the diagonal identity morphisms on $X$ to this diagram where there's a "$*$", AMScd doesn't let me draw those.)

This diagram is a composition of the definition diagram of the diagonal of $X\times X$ and the definition of the product $f\times f$. This shows that indeed $\delta_X\circ f\times f$ is a product morphism in $\text{Hom}(X, Y\times Y)$ of $f:X\rightarrow Y$ and $f:X\rightarrow Y$.

On the other hand also consider the diagram:

$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
@.X\\
@.@V{f}VV\\
@.Y\\
@.*@V{\delta_Y}VV *\\
Y@<{\pi_Y}<<Y\times Y @>{\pi'_Y}>> Y\\
\end{CD}$

(Again please draw in your mind the diagonal arrows that are identity morphisms from $Y$ to $Y$ at the "$*$".)

This diagram is a composition of the morphism $f$ and the definition of the diagonal on $Y$. It shows that $f\circ\delta_Y$ is also a product morphism in $\text{Hom}(X, Y\times Y)$ of $f:X\rightarrow Y$ and $f:X\rightarrow Y$. Showing through uniqueness that they must be the same.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think this will work. I need to use either one or both of those functors.

Comment: What functors are you talking about, this is a correct answer. Please just draw the two diagrams on a piece of paper, and try to understand why they prove $\delta_X\circ f\times f = f\circ \delta_Y$.

Comment: I am not saying your answer is wrong. I liked your answer (+1) but It's not the one I am looking for.

Comment: @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost could you maybe clarify what you find lacking from this answer? I am not seeing it, it only uses the definition of product objects/arrows and diagonal mappings